# Use .bat variables as parameters when calling s PS1 script within a batch script

Tags: function, powershell, batch-file, parameters

I am running reports in batch files on several servers and I need to send emails from those batch files calling a PS1 script. When using a specific set of recipients, subject and body, it is working all fine. The issue is, I need the PS1 script to pick those 3 parameters from what they are in the BAT file as they change in every report. I am a LINUX head so struggling with the logic here and any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

PS1 script... (all the $ variables are defined in the ps1 script and the $arg1,2,3 are defined as below)

```
$arg1=$args[0]
$arg2=$args[1]
$arg3=$args[2]

Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $args1 -Subject $args2 -Body $arg3 -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $MailCredential
```

---

Batch script

```
SET ROOT_DIR=\\FILEZ01.PATH.COM\INFO$\\OUTPUT\REPORTS
set FILE_NAME=%s_date%_MY_FILE.txt
set REC_LIST=itsme@myemail.com
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\Tasks\scripts\SMTP.ps1' -To %REC_LIST% -Subject "ART Delta Patron test" -Body "%ROOT_DIR%\%FILE_NAME%""
```

Comment: Try using `'` instead of `"` inside the cmdline string: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\Tasks\scripts\SMTP.ps1' -To %REC_LIST% -Subject 'ART Delta Patron test' -Body '%ROOT_DIR%\%FILE_NAME%'"`

Comment: Hi Mathias. thanks for the hint. I am sorry I wasn't clear enough in my initial input. The issue seems to be with the PS1 script as the error I am getting is``` "Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'To'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
command again." ``` I believe I need some help with the PowerShell function to get these parameters required in the Batch file

Comment: You're using `$arg1` in the first line, but then you use `$args1` (notice the extra `s`) when you invoke `Send-MailMessage`. Fix that :)

Comment: I have fixed that, thanks. But the issue still persists. I believe it has something to do with the way the parameters should be defined within the PS1 so it is called on the CMD line when executing the script. That is where I am stuck

Comment: You'll want to add `param($To,$Subject,$Body)` to the top of your PowerShell script. You can skip the steps with `$args`, and then do a single statement `Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom @PSBoundParameters -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $MailCredential` (`$PSBoundParameters` will contain the arguments passed to the script by the bat script).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make named parameters work, declare a `param(...)` block on the first line of the script:

```
param($To,$Subject,$Body)
```

Now PowerShell will automatically bind any argument passed to `-To` to the `$To` variable inside the script.

Since all the parameters are named the same in your script and the target cmdlet, you can pass them all along by [splatting `$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom @PSBoundParameters -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $MailCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $Env:BatchVar instead.

I don't have the time to test or debug this, but in general it should look something like this:

Batch file:

```
SET ROOT_DIR=\\FILEZ01.PATH.COM\INFO$\\OUTPUT\REPORTS
set FILE_NAME=%s_date%_MY_FILE.txt
SET To=itsme@myemail.com
SET Subject=ART Delta Patron test
SET Body=%ROOT_DIR%\%FILE_NAME%
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\Tasks\scripts\SMTP.ps1' "
```

PowerShell:

```
Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $Env:To -Subject $Env:Subject -Body $Env:Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $MailCredential
```

Comment: You are welcome.  It's the byproduct of Batch bootstrap for PowerShell I've been working on.  I finally realized that every method of passing values from Batch to PowerShell parameters was either simple and dangerous, or complex and still couldn't be trusted.  But Batch can save anything to the environment variables, and PowerShell reads those environment variables as is, no expanding, no changes to special characters, nothing.  Short of saving info to a file in Batch and reading it back in PowerShell, I really don't believe there are any other viable options.